# HTACCESS Rewrite Help - SEO Trailing Slash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**My Working URL:**
http://www.mydomain.com/user/

**Broken URL:**
http://www.mydomain.com/user

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /lookup.asp?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

How can I modify my current code so that the url works with or without a trailing slash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add just a `?` to your RegEx, to make the `/` optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /lookup.asp?q=$1 [NC,L]
```

In this way, both URLs are working.

Or you could just remove the slash.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked great! I added RewriteCond $1 !=directoryname, to ignore certain directories too. Thanks a million.